# Nested class and save json problem in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have this code to save json, but instead of add new Gift everytime I hit button, it only replace the second part of GiftDetails with new data.

What code i need to edit or add to prevent this happen so it gonna add new GiftDetail perfectly?

My json:

```
{
    "GValue": 1,
    "GName": "Father Gift",
    "GiftDetails": [
      {
        "GDetailValue": 5,
        "GDetailName": "3",
        "GDetailWeight": 2.0,
        "GDetailAmount": 4
      },
      {
        "GDetailValue": 2,
        "GDetailName": "Gift1",
        "GDetailWeight": 11.0,
        "GDetailAmount": 213
      }
    ]
  },
```

My class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class GiftDetail
{
    public int GDetailValue;
    public string GDetailName;
    public double GDetailWeight;
    public int GDetailAmount;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Gift
{

    public int GValue;
    public string GName;
    public List<GiftDetail> GiftDetails;
}
```

My button:

```
            GiftDetail NewGiftDetail = new GiftDetail
            {
                GDetailValue = 5,
                GDetailAmount = 4,
                GDetailName = "Gift1",
                GDetailWeight = 2,
            };

            Gift NewGift = new Gift
            {
                GValue = DropDownValueQua,
                GName = txtDropDownQuaTxt,
                GiftDetails = new List<GiftDetail>() { NewGiftDetail }
            };

            if (_Gift.Exists(x => x.GValue == 1 ))//&&_Gift.Exists(x => x.GDetailValue == DropDownValuePhanQua))
             //dont' know how to call GDetailValue here
            {
              GiftDetail NewGiftDetail3 = new GiftDetail
              {
                 GDetailValue = DropDownValuePhanQua,
                 GDetailAmount = iSoLuongPhanQua,
                 GDetailName = ifTenPhanQua.text,
                 GDetailWeight = fTileRaPhanQua,
              };

              int i = 0;

              while (i <_Gift.Count && _Gift[i].GValue != 1)// &&_Gift[i].GDetailValue !=DropDownValuePhanQua)
               //and here
                    i++;


              _Gift.RemoveAt(i);
              Debug.Log(  "Edit Success");
              NewGift.GiftDetails.Add(NewGiftDetail3);

            }
            _Gift.Add(NewGift);
            SaveToJson(_Gift, DATABASE_NAME);
```

And how to access GDetailValue = 2 so i can delete,edit only that Gift from database without affect other Gift. 
Is there any way like this?

```
if (_Gift.Exists(x => x.GValue == DropDownValueQua ))
```

but instead of

X.GValue it is X.GiftDetail.GDetailAmount ???

If I missing something so you guy don't understand just tell me ^_^

---

---

This is what I just find out, It work great if I create Father Gift in the right order, if wrong order than it will said index was out of range. Anyway to get the right order so i can add child gift?

```
GiftDetail NewGiftDetail3 = new GiftDetail
        {
            GDetailValue = DropDownValuePhanQua,
            GDetailAmount = iSoLuongPhanQua,
            GDetailName = ifTenPhanQua.text,
            GDetailWeight = fTileRaPhanQua,
        };
        bool isGiftFound = false;
        int s = 0;
        while (s < _Gift.Count) //&& isGiftFound == false)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < _Gift[s].GiftDetails.Count; z++)
            {
                if (_Gift[s].GiftDetails[z].GDetailValue == DropDownValuePhanQua && _Gift[s].GValue==DropDownValueQua)
                {
                    isGiftFound = true;
                    string qweqw = _Gift[s].GiftDetails[z].GDetailName.ToString();
                    Debug.Log(qweqw);
                    _Gift[s].GiftDetails.RemoveAt(z);
                    _Gift[s].GiftDetails.Add(NewGiftDetail3);
                }
                else {

                }

            }
            s++;

        }


        if (isGiftFound == false)
        {
            _Gift[DropDownValueQua-1].GiftDetails.Add(NewGiftDetail3);
            //this code fail if I don't create Father Gift in right order of DropDownValueQua. Is there anyway else.
        }
```

Comment: I dont think it can be anything else, because the list is called GiftDetail, even as array, it would be that..

Comment: @BugFinder I find a way around to do it, but now i have problem with get the right Father Gift to add child Gift into. I just add my code

Comment: ok, but a new question should be a new post not tacked on the end of this one. nor replaced by the new question

Comment: But i did ask first how to add child Gift to father Gift perfect in the beginning though.  The sub question is how to call GDetailValue=2.

Answer (score 0):

> And how to access GDetailValue = 2

If all you need is to compare the `GDetailValue` with the value of dropdownValue that you receive from user input, Try the below line

```
var resultGift = gift.GiftDetails.FirstOrDefault(gd => gd.GDetailValue == DropDownValuePhanQua);
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: I use this and resultGift return null even though GDetailValue and DropDownValuePhanQua have the same value, it didn't let me access GiftDetails if i don't do this _Gift[0].GiftDetails

Comment: var resultGift = _Gift[0].GiftDetails.FirstOrDefault(gd => gd.GDetailValue == DropDownValuePhanQua);

Comment: if only compare i think this is better                                                                  if(_Gift[i].GiftDetails.Exists(x => x.GDetailValue == DropDownValuePhanQua )) but than i can get the GiftDetail[] place to delete, edit it.